# How to Call Controller Function From jQuery If Using Strict DI

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In my current application I already called many AngularJS controller function from jQuery but I just started using `strict-di` directive and now its giving me an error that `angular().element()` not defined something like this.

I searched too much about this issue on Angular site and StackOverflow as well but didn't find any solution, I have 30-40 controllers and in all somehow I call function from jQuery so I can't change it is there any way to keep my all codes and also use `strict-di` ?

Also using :

```
app.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
      $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
    }]);
```

and getting undefined error in :

```
var myVar = angular.element(document.getElementById('ControllerID')).scope().FunctionName();
```

TIA

Comment: Do you have a sample of the code that has this issue? I was able to use jQuery with angular with the strict di directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `strict-di` is your problem.

As per the documentation for scope() - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element > jQuery/jqLite Extras > Methods > scope()

> ...Requires Debug Data to be enabled.

Your

```
$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
```

disables Debug Data and so scope() on angular.element(document.getElementById('ControllerID')) returns undefined.

Try setting

```
$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(true);
```

Comment: any other way to do it ?

Comment: I think not - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9515 was the github issue for this and it was closed by updating the documentation. But why would you need it? You can use  angular.reloadWithDebugInfo()  if you want to temporarily debug.